# What is the most elegant way to cast a variable you just received as an argument?

Tags: java, graphics

More specifically, what's the most elegant way to cast the Graphics object in a paint() call up to a Graphics2D object?

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // How do I convert/cast/etc the g variable to a Graphics2D object?
}
```

Or am I missing the point here? Is there a better way to handle this in general?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
```

There is no need to be fancy about it.

You will always receive a G2D in the paint method.

I even like to call the `Graphics` parameter `g2` and then cast to a `Graphics2D` named `g` to make using it simpler.

Comment: So you always receive one? Why are the arguments in the declaration "Graphics g" and there is no "Graphics2D g" alternative to override? Internally is a Graphics2D object being cast to a Graphics object for backward compatibility and then you're able to restore it to a Graphics2D if you need to?

Comment: You are being given a Graphics object for some historical reason that I have grown to not care about.  I just always do the cast if I need G2D methods.

Comment: You might want to use g as the Graphics2D variable as it is going to be used throughout the code. You could also have a general component and forward to a renderer using an interface that uses Graphics2D instead of Graphics for parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
Graphics2D g2 = Graphics2D.class.cast(g);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't do much in this situation.
You can validate that you actually got a Graphics2D object before casting. But, as far as I know, you can get anything else anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like

```
Graphics2D g2 = g as Graphics2D;
if (g2 == null)
//do stuff
```

But as said before, no reason to make it anymore complicated than it is :P

Comment: Oh, it's java .. My bad. I was sleepy :O

Answer (score 0):

Its not directly relevant, but in Scala they recognised this "unpleasantness" - and encourage you to use pattern matching to deal with the correct class instead of a cast:

```
g match { 
     case Graphics2D(g2d) => //code goes here !
     case _ => Nothing //or throw exception etc
}
```

They actively discourage casts (there is no special cast syntax, only a method).

Not entirely relevant to you, but thought its worth noting that others are troubled by what troubles you ;)